# two figures side by side with a single caption using floatrow

Tags: floatrow

I use the `floatrow` package to place figures side by side and have now difficulties in a case I want to have a single caption for two figures side by side.

The code

```
\begin{figure}[!ht]
    \centering
        \begin{floatrow}
        \ffigbox  
        {     \caption{a}
            \label {fig:fig4ss}
        }
        {   \includegraphics{figures/fig4sa}}
        \ffigbox   
        {     \caption{b}
            \label{fig:fig4sb}
        } 
        {   \includegraphics{figures/fig4sb}}
        \end{floatrow}
\end{figure}
```

produces two figures each with a caption and a number. I assume that adding a caption and label command at the top would produce a single caption and a single figure number and replace the two caption and label commands for each figure.

```
\begin{figure}[!ht]
    \centering
    {  \caption{Two generator partitions for two properties} 
        \label{fig:fig4sa}
    }
        \begin{floatrow}
        \ffigbox  
        {   \includegraphics{figures/fig4sa}}
        \ffigbox   
        {   \includegraphics{figures/fig4sb}}
        \end{floatrow}
\end{figure}
```

Unfortunately, this produces an error (missing `}` but i have the impression that all `{` are balanced).

Is this not possible with `floatrow`?

Comment: Do you want the two figures to be considered  subfigures?

Comment: for what you like to obtain you not need a `floatrow`: `\begin{figure}\centering\caption{...}\label{...} \includegraphics[width=0.45\linewidth]{figures/fig4sa}}\hfil\includegraphics[width=0.45\linewidth]{figures/fig4sb}}\end{figure}` should be sufficient.